# Criar cabeçalho (de linhas) da matriz no DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Teria de alguma maneira no C# usar essa coluna apontada da imagem para adicionar valor nela como se fosse um "cabeçalho"?

Estou usando o `DataGridView` abaixo para mostrar uma matriz. O cabeçalho da matriz já está sendo mostrado nas colunas porque eu consigo usar:

```
gridView.Columns.Add("string", "header");
```

[image: DataGridView]

Comment: Eu teria que usar uma coluna dentro da row para ser meu cabeçalho então?

Comment: @Bart Não precisa adicionar coluna não

Comment: @jbueno como assim?

Comment: @Bart Quis dizer que você pode sim adicionar valores neste espaço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso **realmente** é um cabeçalho da linha (*row header*) e é perfeitamente possível adicionar valores nele.

Só é preciso usar a propriedade `HeaderCell` da linha.

```
private void SetarCabecalhoLinha(DataGridView dgv)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow linha in dgv.Rows)
    {
        linha.HeaderCell.Value = (linha.Index + 1).ToString();
    }
}
```